# Remove or add item in ListView on itemTapped event of ListView

Tags: c#, listview, observablecollection

I have list view and its data source is ObservableCollection as given below.

```
    ObservableCollection<empList_Model> diselectEmpModel = new ObservableCollection<empList_Model>();


    ObservableCollection<empList_Model> selectEmpModel = new ObservableCollection<empList_Model>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        selectEmpModel.Add (new empList_Model{ empName = "Employee " + i.ToString (), id = i.ToString () });
             selectEmpModel.Add (new empList_Model{ empName = "Select All ", id = "All" });
             listof_selectEmployee.ItemsSource = selectEmpModel;        

    public void  itemSelectedof_selectEmployeeList(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
            {

                var listview = sender as ListView;
                var itemFor_AddingRemoving = listview.BindingContext as empList_Model;
                selectEmpModel.Remove(itemFor_AddingRemoving);  

                listof_selectEmployee.ItemsSource = selectEmpModel; 

                diselectEmpModel.Add (itemFor_AddingRemoving);
                listof_diselectEmployee.ItemsSource = diselectEmpModel;     


            }
public  class empList_Model
        {
            public string empName{ get; set;}
            public int Selected{ get; set;}
            public string id{ get; set;}
        }
```

**Xaml :**

```
<ListView  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="listof_selectEmployee" ItemSelected="itemSelectedof_selectEmployeeList" BackgroundColor="Gray" RowHeight="40" SeparatorVisibility="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout  Padding="20">                                
                            <Label Text="{Binding empName}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.listTextColor}" />                               
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>


         <ListView  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="listof_diselectEmployee" ItemSelected="itemSelectedof_diselectEmployeeList" BackgroundColor="Silver" RowHeight="40" SeparatorVisibility="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout  Padding="20">                                
                             <Label Text="{Binding empName}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.listTextColor}" />                               
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

So, I have the two ListViews above and I want an item to be removed from the first list and added to the second ListView when a user clicks on any item of first ListView (itemSelectedof_selectEmployeeList() event). For some reason, when I tap on any item of ListView, nothing happens. Items are not removed from the first List nor are any added in second List. I don't know what I am missing.